# VLookup against 2 ranges - one exact one Non-Exact

Tags: excel

I have two data sets:

Set1: Name, Date, Amount

Set2: Name, Amount, StartDate, End Date

In Set1 I am trying to populate the Amount field with the data from Set2.  The issue is that the key field is a mix of exact match (Name) and Non-exact match (Date Range).

How can I write a formula to lookup the Amount in Set2 where the Name is an exact match and the Date is within the date range of StartDate and EndDate?

I have tried a lot of different functions on this to no avail - VLookups, Lookups, Match and Index, If statements - and Arrays of all of those as well.  The closest I've come is creating a key field that is [StartDate] & [Name] however this fails if multiple names have the same start date (Returns the highest valued one, regardless of name)

Data considerations and assumptions

1. A Name/Date record is unique in Set1
2. No Start and End date ranges will overlap for a given Name
   a.  Start and End Date ranges may overlap for different Names
3. All Name/Date combinations from Set1 will have a matching record in Set2
4. A user should be able to add a new Name and Amount in Set2 without a negative impact

Thank you!  I tried to provide as much detail as I can here, but any additional questions, please let me know.

Comment: please post some sample data. you can do it in excel and copy/paste a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SUMPRODUCT` formula will do nicely (as long as you have excel 2016 or greater).

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A20=$A$27:$A$30)*(B20<=$D$27:$D$30)*(B20>=$C$27:$C$30)*($B$27:$B$30))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great!  Using SumProduct this way is an awesome solution, thank you!